# Syntax for rendeing a zend form in a non zend project

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm using zend form in a non-zend project and I'm able to access `Zend_Form` fine from my custom class `Custom_Form`. Then in the file where I want to render my form, I create an instance of my form, but then I'm not sure how to render it.

```
$form = new Custom_Form();
//how to render the form here
var_dump($form); //var_dump looks busy so couldn't find info from it
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, you need an view script and than call the render(); method.

```
$view = new Zend_View();
$view->doctype('XHTML1_TRANSITIONAL');

$form = new Custom_Form();
$form->setView(new Zend_View());

echo $form->render();
```

Comment: thank you. By the way I used `setView($view)` instead of creating a `setView(new Zend_View())` to take advantage of the `doctype` above. So what's the purpose of this doctype? since it works just fine without it.